# Read facebook ads stats without app on their white list?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I need to download ads statistics from Facebook. I use .NET library [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/), but I finished with *(294) Managing advertisements requires the extended permission ads_management, and a participating API key*.

I have *ads_management* rights already set, but I read I have to be on application whitelist - which I'm not. Does it really mean I have to wait now for 2 or 3 weeks till Facebook decide to put my app (which does not exists yet!) on some white list? There is no other way to read stats without application?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct! Access to the Ads-API is heavily restricted through Facebooks PMD-program:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/
https://developers.facebook.com/preferredmarketingdevelopers/ads-api-access/

Comment: So if I understand correct, I register my app from my own account and if Facebook approves it, every my client can use it (and download its own ads statistics) since he grants rights to my app, right?